# In Microsoft Flow how do I grab an excel column and format as time for an email alert?

Tags: office365, office365-apps, power-automate

I'm trying to use Microsoft Flow to watch a Sharepoint Excel document and send an email if a certain condition is true in a table.

The email successfully contains the time column but the time looks like this: `0.569444444444444` rather than a nice formatted `13:40:00`.

In my email alert this expression works to grab the value though it is formatted as 0.569444444444444...

```
item()?['Time Column']
```

When I read the documentation and try to format it nicely using this command however the Flow fails.

```
formatDateTime(item()?['Time Column'],'hh:mm:ss')
```

What am I doing wrong? Any advice? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This value `0.569444444444444` is a decimal representation for Excel time `13:40:00`.
For example `0.04167` is decimal representation for `1 hour`, `1.0` is equivalent of `1 day`.

[image: excel]

The point is to exctract hours, minutes and seconds from it which is not very hard but a little bit messy with built-in MS Flow functions:

`split(string(mul(variables('time_decimal'),int(24))),'.')[0]` returns hour

`split(string(add(mul(int(60),sub(mul(variables('time_decimal'),int(24)),float(variables('hours')))),float(0.00000001))),'.')[0]` returns minutes and so on.

Comment: Thanks you very much for your insight. I do get the following error. It seems that the flow from excel doesn't put the column into a 'variable'. This still doesn't leave me able to access the Excel columns to calculate the time. Any suggestions? `The inputs of workflow run action 'Send_me_an_email_notification' of type 'ApiConnection' are not valid. The variable 'Time Column' must be initialized before it can be used inside action 'Send_me_an_email_notification'.`

Comment: It looks like the variable `Time Column` has not already been initialized with an `Initialize variable` action

Answer (score 0):

Following the above I got this better solution (without adding 0.00001) for rendering the time as hh:mm:ss, which basically use arrays and subctractions. You can either concatenate the 3 functions below and the ":" or to use compose and add these, separated by ":". Just replace DecimalTimeVar with your variable for decimal time. I have cast it as float, so it works with any initial variable (string or float)

HRS
if(equals(length(split(string(mul(float(DecimalTimeVar),int(24))),'.')[0]),1),concat(0,split(string(mul(float(DecimalTimeVar),int(24))),'.')[0]),split(string(mul(float(DecimalTimeVar),int(24))),'.')[0])

MIN
if(equals(length(split(string(mul(float(concat('0.',split(string(mul(float(DecimalTimeVar),int(24))),'.')[1])),int(60))),'.')[0]),1),concat(0,split(string(mul(float(concat('0.',split(string(mul(float(DecimalTimeVar),int(24))),'.')[1])),int(60))),'.')[0]),split(string(mul(float(concat('0.',split(string(mul(float(DecimalTimeVar),int(24))),'.')[1])),int(60))),'.')[0])

SEC
if(equals(length(split(string(mul(float(concat('0.',split(string(mul(float(concat('0.',split(string(mul(float(DecimalTimeVar),int(24))),'.')[1])),int(60))),'.')[1])),int(60))),'.')[0]),1),concat(0,split(string(mul(float(concat('0.',split(string(mul(float(concat('0.',split(string(mul(float(DecimalTimeVar),int(24))),'.')[1])),int(60))),'.')[1])),int(60))),'.')[0]),split(string(mul(float(concat('0.',split(string(mul(float(concat('0.',split(string(mul(float(DecimalTimeVar),int(24))),'.')[1])),int(60))),'.')[1])),int(60))),'.')[0])

Comment: Please use code formatting for readability, Either place code between triple backticks, or indent 4 spaces. Look in the help for how to format an answer.